# Node.js JWT token isn't get passed to another page

Tags: node.js, jwt

First of all sorry if this subject already exists. I have problem with jwt token. I got register/login system in nodejs with mongodb. After I login (at localhost:3000/auth/login), my token is generated, but when i try to access another page (ex. localhost:3000/priv) it responds access denied. It look like the token has to pass with new request to another page, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Jwt token doesn't work like cookies in the browser

You've to manually store the token to the `localStorage` or other `storage` in frontend after login & then attach that jwt token accessing from `localStorage` to `Authorization` header while requesting to another route

You can learn this entire process from https://auth0.com. They've a great tutorial on it. Also learn about access-token & refresh-token mechanism to ensure better security

Comment: Just to add to this, but you shouldn't use localstorage for the token, while it will work its cleartext meaning anyone could copy the token and use it. Its better to use a secure cookie to store it / access it.

Comment: You can use JWT tokens inside a cookie. You can store whatever you like inside a cookie, as long it can be represented as text. Here is a link that shows how to store a JWT inside a cookie, listing its advantages and pitfalls: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/react-authentication-how-to-store-jwt-in-a-cookie-346519310e81.